# How to create and associate SSH public key to a user created in IAM Identity Center?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'd like to associate an SSH public key to my current user which I created from IAM Identity Center so that I can use it for AWS Code Commit.

I am the admin and root.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to use **IAM Identity Center**? It is used for "Single Sign-On" purposes. You possibly just want to use a normal **IAM User**. (Confusing names, eh!)

Comment: Thanks. I am starting with  a free AWS account. I have a root account and i was recommended to use AWS org account admin via identity center. I guess I need to create another one via IAM user and use it for codecommit and normal dev/ops.. ?

Comment: Correct. Unless you are configuring AWS for use by multiple staff members in a large company, stay away from IAM Identity Center. Use IAM instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, that option is not available for IAM Identity Center users. There's no option for that. Access to CodeCommit is managed via policy in your permission sets.

> ... the user’s access is controlled with federated login via AWS SSO. You can grant that access using AWS native authentication, which eliminates the need for a Git credential helper, SSH, and GPG keys. In addition, this allows the administrator to control access by adding or removing the user’s IAM role access.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/federated-multi-account-access-for-aws-codecommit/

You can add CodeCommit policy to your user's permission set or you can create a separate permission set with just CodeCommit policy.

This is how it would look like if you create a separate permission set for it and having multiple permission set for a user.
[image]

After setting up the permission, you need to use `git-remote-codecommit`. You can install it using Python `pip`.

```
pip install git-remote-codecommit
```

Once you login to your SSO via CLI or by exporting the temporary credentials from SSO portal, you can access your repository by:

```
git clone codecommit::{aws-region}://MyAwesomeRepository
```

Answer (score -1):

Select the 'Security Credentials' tab -> Locate the SSH public key for AWS CodeCommit -> Click on 'Upload Public Key' in the upper-right corner -> Upload the previously generated public key content.
or
https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/661505720

Comment: IAM Identity Center (formerly known as AWS SSO) is different from IAM. The option for additional credentials such as SSH key or HTTPS credentials for CodeCommit is not available for IAM Identity Center users.